# "WordPress Projects Not Starting with Docker Compose on Linux - Docker Issues and Denied Access"

Tags: linux, wordpress, docker, docker-compose, podman

My WordPress projects are not coming up. They used to come up on my local host using Docker Compose on Linux, and everything was fine with no issues. However, I don't know what happened, but now my projects are not coming up, and I'm getting an error saying Docker doesn't exist, and the socket is not active, and so on. After a lot of attempts to fix it, I've reached this error that's driving me crazy. No matter what I do, I can't get it to work, and the system even denies access, even through root.

Friends, I would appreciate it if you could guide me. Thank you. "

```
[artpy@fedora guilds2]$ docker-compose up
[+] Running 4/4
 ✔ Network guilds2_default      Created                                    0.0s 
 ✔ Container guilds2-adminer-1  Created                                    0.0s 
 ✔ Container guilds2-db-1       Created                                    0.0s 
 ✔ Container guilds2-wp-1       Created                                    0.0s 
Attaching to guilds2-adminer-1, guilds2-db-1, guilds2-wp-1
Error response from daemon: crun: write to `/proc/self/oom_score_adj`: Permission denied: OCI permission denied
[artpy@fedora guilds2]$
```

I reinstalled the sockets and also reinstalled Docker Compose.
I also reinstalled Podman.
I even created another user on my Linux system and tried that approach, but the problem was not resolved."

Comment: Probably this bug https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/19930

Comment: Please re-read the guidance for the tags you've used.  This is clearly a question about system configuration, not about __programming__, so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  It _might_ be suitable for [wordpress.se] or [sf]: consult the Help Centre for the site before you post.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue trying to run a project locally with docker compose up. I think Podman might've messed with your WSL. So, reinstalling WSL might get it to work.

I used Rancher Desktop and Podman. What I did to fix my issue was to uninstall Podman, then Rancher Desktop and finally WSL. Then reinstall Rancher Desktop which automatically installs WSL. I didn't reinstall Podman.

Comment: I appreciate your response. However, I have downgraded crun, and now everything is functioning correctly.